# Is it possible to assign different page layouts to different users having same profile and user license?

Tags: administration

I have requirement to assign different page layouts to different users having same profile and user license.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Salesforce docs](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_layoutassign.htm)  :

> A user’s profile determines which page layout he or she sees. In
>   addition, if your organization is using record types for a particular
>   tab, the combination of the user’s profile and the record type
>   determine which page layout is displayed.

You cannot just assign different layouts to users having same profile. The only way to do that would be if these layouts are specific to [Record Type](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_recordtype.htm&language=en_US)

For Example: you could do a workflow rule that changes record type based on some custom field. Note that even with this solution the change to layout will only apply on save so it's not a perfect fit.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to assign different users different page layouts if they are having same profile as page layout is assigned at profile level and not at user level.